# Why is id=num acceptable as a field lookup in django?

Tags: python, django, web, django-queryset

Like we can see here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#get

> Entry.objects.get(id='foo')

Shouldn't only Entry.objects.get(id__exact='foo') acceptable? Can we substitute id with other fields like get(name='bar')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[And a little deeper in...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups-intro)

> If you don’t provide a lookup type – that is, if your keyword argument doesn’t contain a double underscore – the lookup type is assumed to be `exact`.

And yes, you can use any field you can provide an equivalent Python type for.